# Intersection of a MeshRegion and InfinitePlane

Tags: regions, intersection

The documentation says that `RegionIntersection` is not implemented for MeshRegion objects embedded in 3D. But I have one such region and would like to slice it with xy, yz, and xz planes, and I can't figure out how.

Here are two example inputs regions:

```
r1 = RegionBoundary@ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 3}]]
r2 = InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]
```

and this is what I've tried that fails:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can intersect 3D primitives separately:

```
Show[r1, Graphics3D[
  DeleteCases[RegionIntersection[r2, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[r1, 2], _EmptyRegion]]]
```

[image]

The intersection is a set of lines since `r1` is a boundary region.

Comment: I tried this on my machine running version 10.2 and it did not work. However after updating to 10.3 it did.